# Using a diode-connected MOSFETs as a voltage divider

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, voltage-divider

I have read that it is possible to use a diode-connected MOSFET as a small-signal resistor with a resistance of 1/gm (ignoring channel length modulation.)

[image]

Also, the equation for gm is as follows:

[image]

Note that this equation shows that gm is dependent on Vgs (=Vds for diode connected devices.)

If I design this (and select 1/gm) based on a Vin = 5V with the hopes of getting a 0.5 ratio to give Vout = 2.5V, then I change my Vin to 1V, my 1/gm should change, hence my resistance should change and now I will no longer get my 0.5 ratio.

Is that correct? These resistor dividers can only be used for one single designed Vin.

Comment: Did you mean to use mosfets? or JFETs? Enhancement mode mosfets do not conduct until the gate-drain voltage is above a threshold. JFETs are typically depletion mode devices and act as a resistance when the gate-drain voltage is 0.

Comment: If the FETs are matched, their large-signal voltage drops and currents should track together and hence g_ms will track together, maintaining the 0.5 ratio. The same can't be necessarily said for ratios other than 0.5.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy MOSFETs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one neglects the current that may flow through the \$V_{out}\$ connection, then both transistors will have the same current flowing through them. If the transistors have identical characteristics, then each transistor will have the same voltage \$V_{DS}=V_{GS}\$ across it's terminals, both will have the same \$g_m\$. This is true regardless of the applied voltage. If the current you draw from the output is small enough (relative to the current through the transistors), your output will be approximately 0.5 times your input. But that assumes your transistors are perfectly matched and the current drawn from the output is small enough.

> When I change my Vin to 1V, my 1/gm should change, hence my resistance should change and now I will no longer get my 0.5 ratio.

The current through each transistor will change, but they should change equally. (Again, assuming we can neglect the current lost through \$V_{out}\$ connection. The problem however, is that you are using mosfets, which are (generally) enhancement mode devices. They do not conduct appreciably unless the gate-source voltage is at or above a threshold voltage. To get the transitors to conduct with 1V across both, will require a threshold voltage of 0.5V or less.

I don't really really know the details of your application, so the following suggestion may not suit your needs, but you may have better luck with very low voltages if you use identical JFETs configured with their source and gate connected. These will continue to conduct all the way down to 0V.

Or could you simply use resistors?

Edit: The reason why the voltage drop between the two transistors will tend toward equality is as follows. (We will assume there is no output current, at least for now.)

Hopefully you can see that if the transistors have identical characteristics, then if the current through each is equal, the voltages across them will be equal, and vice versa.

Comment: Great Answer. So the gm1 and gm2 should change by the same amount and hence maintain our fixed Vout. Could you just explain a little bit more about how the Vds (= Vgs) of M2 will track with Vin? If Vin increases, gm1 also increases but I am not sure how gm2 also increases too?

Comment: I added an explanation for why the voltages across the transistors will tend to equalize. It may not be the clearest explanation, so let me know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: I wasn't happy with the explanation I gave, so I rewrote my answer. Please reread and let me know if it makes it clearer why, neglecting output current, and assuming identical transistor characteristics, the voltages, and gm of the transistors will track each other.

Comment: Ah. Great answer. So essentially, because the current through the branch is the same, this forces the Id in the square-law equation, thus there is only one remaining variable that can move -> Vgs (=Vds). Hence both transistors settle to the same Vgs value, giving the same resistance to each (matched everything else) and a 0.5 voltage divider.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing up / combining **small signal behavior** and **DC behavior**.

The \$1/g_m\$ "resistance" of a MOSFET (it applies to JFETs and BJTs as well) is **small signal behavior**. So if you have a **small** signal (for example, a sinewave of 10 mV) at \$V_{in}\$ and

\$g_{m,M1}\$ = \$g_{m,M2}\$

then at \$V_{out}\$ you get a half of the input signal (so a sinewave of **5** mV).

If you change \$g_{m,M1}\$ and \$g_{m,M2}\$ you will indeed find that output voltage \$V_{out}\$will follow the resistive divider formula that you show.

However the behavior for DC voltages does not work in the same way. Then the formula \$I_D = \mu C_{OX}\frac W L (V_{GS} - V_{TH})\$ applies. If you would use two identical transistors and make \$V_{in}\$ = 5 V you would get \$V_{out}\$ = 2.5 V (I'm ignoring the [body effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage) here!).

However, if you would make the bottom transistor M2 2 x larger (you could just put two identical MOSFETs in parallel) then you would **not** get \$V_{out}\$ = \$\frac 1 3\ V_{in}\$.

That is so because the threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$ remains the same for M1 and (the double-size) M2. So although \$(V_{GS} - V_{TH})\$ of M2 will be half of the \$I_D = \mu C_{OX}\frac W L (V_{GS} - V_{TH})\$ of M1, this is not true for the threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$.

Look at it this way, if we had transistors with a threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$ = 0 (zero) then we would get:

\$V_{out}\$ = \$\frac 1 3\ V_{in}\$.

But the threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$ is not zero so that "messes up" the voltage division ratio for DC voltages.

Comment: I understand. But in the first scenario you mention, if a sinewave of 5mV is applied to the Vin with a DC value of 5V, the Vout should be 2.5Vdc + 2.5mV sinewave (assuming same sizing), correct? The DC voltage can be included in the small-signal effect so long as we keep it fixed at the value, am I right in saying that? I thought that g_m is a large-signal + small-signal parameter in itself, what makes it small-signal is the assumption that the g_m stays fixed over a small range of Vgs.

Comment: *Vout should be 2.5V + 2.5mV sinewave (assuming same sizing), correct?* Yes correct, assuming M1 and M2 have identical DC conditions. *The DC voltage can be included in the small-signal effect* Not sure what you mean there. How I do this: I **separate** the two, there is an **AC** solution (5 m V => 2.5 mV AC) and there is a **DC** solution (5 V => 2.5 V DC). You can combine the two results for input ( 5 V DC + 5 mV AC) and output (2.5 V DC + 2.5 mV AC) but the calculations remain separate.

Comment: Ahhh. I understand now. I was mixing up 1/gm in my large signal equations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to clarify for any other readers, the flaw in my understanding was that I was using the 1/gm **small-signal** resistance in my large signal analysis. The two signals see different resistances - small-signal sees a voltage divider based on the two 1/gm resistors and large signal sees the square-law equation. Thanks Bimpelrekkie.